# Sass extend with pseudo selectors

Tags: function, sass, extend, mixins

I am using compass to manage some sass files on mac osx. I have these files:

```
sass/
      screen.scss
            partials folder/
      ...
            _fonts.scss
            _functions.scss
      ...
```

In fonts I have this rule which I would like to reuse @extend.

```
//fonts.scss
.icon-ab-logo, {
font-family: 'icomoon';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.icon-ab-logo:before { //i want to reuse this.
content: "\e000";
}
```

In functions I have this screen.scss:

```
.logo {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 500;
width: 9.5em;
background: $logo;
@include transition(all 0.2s);
   &:after{
     @include icon( ".icon-ab-logo" );
   }
 }
```

Finally in functions.scss I call this:

```
    @mixin icon( $icon ){
      font-family: 'icomoon';
      speak: none;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      @extend #{$icon}:before; //<- this is the problem, no errors just isn't parsed.
    }
```

Is there a way to reference .icon-ab-logo:before using a mixin? Workarounds? 
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you want to extend a pseudo class or pseudo element, you just want to extend the parent selector (ie. everything that comes before the colon).

```
%foo:before {
  color: red;
}

.bar {
  @extend %foo;
}
```

Generates:

```
.bar:before {
  color: red;
}
```

So for your instance, what you want to do is this:

```
.icon-ab-logo, {
    font: 100%/1 'icomoon'; // use the shorthand
    speak: none;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

%foo:before, .icon-ab-logo:before { //i want to reuse this.
    content: "\e000";
}

@mixin icon( $icon ){
    font: 100%/1 'icomoon'; // use the shorthand
    speak: none;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    @extend #{$icon};
}

.bar {
    @include icon('%foo');
}
```

Be aware that your mixin generates a *lot* of styles, so it's not really suitable for extensive reuse.  It would make a lot more sense to be extending that as well.

Comment: This does work. But yeah this is not a good idea as you've said. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like SASS doesn't work so well with pseudo elements in extends.

Work around the issue like this:

```
%before-icon
  color: red

.foo
  /* Some styles here */

  &:before
    @extend %before-icon
```

Result:

```
.foo:before {
  color: red;
}

.foo {
  /* Some styles here */
}
```

Also, it looks like you're overcomplicating things. You'll find your code difficult to grasp and maintain.

PS You should keep mixins in `_mixins.scss`.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, you should try to use placeholder class. In other hand always first consider @mixin first and try to avoid nesting with @extend.

Comment: The core principle of the accepted answer is using the extend. However, there are some drawbacks of using a extend. Something why you perhaps also want to avoid it? The biggest drawback is that using extends can become quite messy and doesn't respect source order as explained here: https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-extend-nobody-told-you/.